# Inheritance - variable initialisation in subclass

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I tend to favour composition over inheritance where possible based on what I learnt at university on  "best practices" type course.  I am looking at some code in an application, which looks like this:

```
Public Class A
    Protected _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A
End Class

Public Class C
    Inherits B
End Class

Public Class D
    Inherits C

    Public Sub SomeMethod()
       'This isn't good
       Name = "Ian"
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim d As New D
        d.SomeMethod()
    End Sub

End Class
```

In the example above: Class D is using a public property in class A.  The previous developer has written "this isn't good" above the initialisation of name in class D.  I believe that the reason he has written this comment is due to business rules and not the fact that he has assigned the value of a.Name in class D.  However, I wanted to check if there is anything wrong with the code above.  a.Name is shared by all subclasses.  Classes B,C and D contain lots of overloaded methods so I believe inheritance was the correct design choice in this case.

I wish the previous developer left more documentation.

Comment: Maybe the previous developer's name wasn't Ian ;-)

Comment: I think it is because of the hardcoded string `"Ian"`. Nothing wrong related with inheritance here.

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov, thanks.  I have harcoded "Ian" to explain the question.  Name is actually extracted from the data tier in the application.  Can you write an answer?

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov, are you able to answer my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794957/vb-net-misusing-instance-variables? It is similar.

Comment: @w0051977, yep, already answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing bad in assigning a value to a parent property in a derived class, if that does not break the expected behaviour of parent type (see [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). The type D in your example still can be treated as class A. If changing of Name property is not forbidden behaviour for class A (which I believe is not, because there is a setter for that property), then the assignment is likely not a problem.

Maybe the problem the previous developer addressed in his comment was in taking a value directly from the data layer and not from the business layer?